# Convert bytes data to mp3 file and play

Tags: swift

Here is a snippet of my api call:

`let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`

Here is the output:

`777 bytes`

How can I download and play the audio file on the users machine?

Comment: As I said in your previous question, instead of `let (_, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)`, do `let (fileURL, response) = try await URLSession.shared.downloadTask(for: request)`, you have the URL with the mp3! (if there is no error, obv)

Comment: @Larme I get this error: ```Type of expression is ambiguous without more context```